# Whether allocation order scan is with respect to clustered or non clustered index?

Tags: sql-server

When SQL Server engine decides to perform the allocation order scan, then does it scan the clustered or non clustered index in allocation order?

What happens if there is no index on the table, then on what basis is the allocation order scan performed?

Comment: What do you mean by "order scan"?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server allocation order scans are driven by the allocation information contained in IAM pages.  Each rowstore index or heap will have an IAM page for each 4gb range of the database data files in which it has any database pages.

IAM-driven scans are the only available scan choice for a rowstore heap.  Because the heap does not have an index order in which to organize a scan.

But rowstore indexes - whether non-clustered or clustered - have both IAM pages and a b-tree structure for their index order.  Both non-clustered and clustered indexes have the option of selecting an allocation order scan or an index order scan.

More detailed information from this Paul White blog post.

Allocation Order Scans
2015 January 23
https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/allocation-order-scans